# Run a function once all children element are _actually_ updated

Tags: polymer, lit-element, lit-html

In lit-html we have the `firstUpdated()` method to run one-time initialisations once an element is rendered.

What if you need to run a function only once all children within that template are updated?
And what if your template includes native form elements and custom ones?

Right now I am doing a terrible:

```
  firstUpdated () {
    super.firstUpdated()

    setTimeout(() => this.onceChildrenAreUpdated(), 100)
  }
```

Surely there is a better way?
I realise it's tricky, because for lit-element "rendered" means that the DOM is done; it doesn't mean that all elements inside have done whichever initialisation then want to do.

But still...

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). What is the root problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: The containing element needs to run some methods on the contained element. However, those methods only work once the contained elements are fully initialised, which is an async process. This is the X problem.

Comment: I thought that firstupdated only ran after the render was completely finished, but in case that doesn't work, I think you could fire events on every children element's firstupdated and listen to those on the parent

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can wait for all the children to be updated:

```
  async firstUpdated () {
    const children = this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('*'));
    await Promise.all(Array.from(children).map((c) => c.updateComplete));
    this.onceChildrenAreUpdated();
  }
```

Replace `querySelectorAll('*')` with something more specific if possible.

Comment: Thanks for answering Justin! I have   

async _allChildrenCompleted () {
    // Wait for all children to be ready to rock and roll
    for (const el of this.elements) {
      // TODO: What about React, Vue, etc.? Uniform API across element libraries?
      if (typeof el.updateComplete !== 'undefined') {
        await el.updateComplete
      }
    }
  }

Comment: Promise.all is meant to be less blocking, but I doubt it will make a meaningful difference for me. But... if the elements I am cycling through are made by other libraries, this won't work. Is there any hope to have a semi-standard API where an element returns true to a promise once it's fully ready to go?

Comment: Unrelated: I would love to hear your comments on this [Redux replacement](https://github.com/mobily-enterprises/reducs/blob/master/reducs.js) and this [example of use with lit-html](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/lacy-ornament)